# python scrape html font tag

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am new to programming and python in particular. I cannot scrape font tag text from html. Here is my code.I need to extract all text between  and count it. I don't know what I am not taking into consideration cos getting empty respond from running the program.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">&quot;amy in marketing press one amanda in groups press two to repeat this menu press star&quot;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><BR>
</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">Labels:<FONT COLOR="#ff0000">Machine-Message,In-House-Alternative,Company-Alternative;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#00b050">Machine-Message,</FONT><FONT COLOR="#00b050">Greetings-Other;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#0070c0">Machine-Message,</FONT>
<FONT COLOR="#0070c0">Personal-Information;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><BR>
</P>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.find('FONT', COLOR="#ff0000"))
```

Comment: I missed " during writing the post, but result is same , empty []

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a quotes " and use lower case tag name in soup.find or for getting all occurences find_all

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">&quot;amy in marketing press one amanda in groups press two to repeat this menu press star&quot;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><BR>
</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">Labels:<FONT COLOR="#ff0000">Machine-Message,In-House-Alternative,Company-Alternative;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#00b050">Machine-Message,</FONT><FONT COLOR="#00b050">Greetings-Other;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#0070c0">Machine-Message,</FONT>
<FONT COLOR="#0070c0">Personal-Information;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><BR>
</P>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.find("font", color="#ff0000").text)
```

Comment: Rakesh, it is now much better, I am getting something. Now I need to get only text without mentioning tags : <font color="#ff0000">Machine-Message,In-House-Alternative,Company-Alternative;</font>

Comment: @TiriTaka I have added the changes

Comment: Thanking a lot for this progress. But it is still not full goal of my task. I will extend html. I need from this  to found out how many times 'Machine-Message" is repeated in this document, actually I need to count how many time each label is repeated in this doc.

Comment: add this to old html
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">@377, 136163000006,</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">&quot;thank you for calling quick help
a lot and grill press one for private party information press two for
to go orders press three for reservations&quot;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><BR>
</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">Labels:<FONT COLOR="#ff0000">Machine-Message,Company-Type;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#00b050">Machine-Message,
Company-Type;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#0070c0">Machine-Message,
Company-Type;</FONT></P>

Comment: Please don't put large slabs of code into comments. It belongs in the question itself, and it's painful to read in a comment.